# main arguments and functions in c

Tags: c, program-entry-point

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int n){

int doenstwork = n * 2;

return doesntwork;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int n;

n = atoi(argv[1]);

return multiply(n);

}
```

I compile but when i run it with an argument I see nothing. Compiled it with gcc -std=c99 filename.c -g.

Comment: What does the compiler say? The code you posted won't compile and it has nothing to do with arguments.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int n){

int doenstwork = n * 2;

return doesntwork;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int n;

n = atoi(argv[1]);

return multiply(n);

}

Comment: If you want to edit your question, click the edit button, don't post a comment.

Comment: Also, you should explain how exactly doesn't it work. What is the expected behavior? What does the code actually do?

Answer (score 1):

With the updated code in your question, you have several problems:

1. You have a typo: you declare a variable `doenstwork`, but then you try to refer to `doesntwork`.
2. Since you say you're able to compile and run your program, what you posted is obviously not the same as what you're actually running. *Always* copy-and-paste your exact code. If you re-type it, you'll make mistakes like this, and those of us trying to help you can't tell the difference between mistakes you made entering the code in your question and mistakes that are actually in the code you're compiling and running.
3. The value returned from `main` is the *status* of your program, not its output. On Unix-like systems, all but the low-order 8 bits of this value are ignored, so this is not a good way for your program to return detailed information.

Once I corrected the typo, I was able to use your program:

```
$ gcc c.c -o c
$ ./c 7 ; echo $?
14
```

but it works only for a small range of values:

```
$ ./c 1000 ; echo $?
208
```

The status of a program is used to indicate whether it succeeded or failed, and possibly to return a *small* amount of information about why it failed. Returning a value of 0 denotes successful execution; returning `EXIT_FAILURE` (defined in `<stdlib.h>`) denotes failure. On Unix-like systems, usually `EXIT_FAILURE == 1`; sometimes a value like 2 is used to denote a different kind of failure. For example, `grep` returns a status of 0 if a match was found, 1 if no match was found, and 2 if something else went wrong (such as a malformed regular expression or a missing file).

To get information out of a program, the simplest way is to print that information in text form to standard output. You can replace

```
return multiply(n);
```

by

```
printf("%d\n", multiply(n));
```

You can add a `return 0;` after that; as of C99 it's not required, but it's not a bad idea to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't define the variable "doesntwork". This shouldn't compile.
2. You don't end your function "multiply" with a closing bracket. This shouldn't compile.
3. You don't include a function prototype for the function "multiply". This shouldn't compile.
4. If your IDE is so lazy that it will compile this then how do you know that it "didn't work"? Maybe it returned some int to the OS.

Comment: For reference, `}` is a "brace".  `]` is a "bracket".

Comment: Okay i fixed all but dont know what this mean: You don't include a function prototype for the function "multiply". This shouldn't compile.

Comment: @user2682811, Billy Bob is wrong about that.  Your code doesn't need a forward declaration since `multiply` is declared before `main`.

Comment: Still doesn't work... Can compile but when sending an argument I get segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Actually Billy Bob is correct. Different IDEs and compilers require different levels of strictness. Full ANSI/ISO compliance, requiring prototypes, etc. can save you a lot of trouble. Your compiler SHOULD require a prototype.

The line:

```
n = atoi(argv[1]);
```

is suspicious as well because in C arrays are indexed from zero so the first item in your array should be `argv[0]`.

Comment: No, the use of `argv[1]` is not particularly suspicious. `argv[0]` points to a string representing the program name; `argv[1]` points to the first command-line argument. (Note that `argv[1]` will be a null pointer if no arguments are supplied; you need to check for that, probably by examining the value of `argc`.) Incidentally, the ISO C standard does not require prototypes; as of the 1999 standard any call requires a visible *declaration*, but that declaration needn't be a prototype (i.e., it needn't specify parameter types). But all function declarations in standard headers are prototypes.